# php: set curly brackets in the first two characters in a string

Tags: php, brackets

My question is the following:
I need to set curly brackets in the first two characters in a string

```
$string = "We want home";

echo $string;
```

I want to echo this:

```
(We) Want home
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried something ? (Try with [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) `echo "(" . substr($string, 0, 2) . ")" . substr($string,2);`)

Comment: Just put them in the string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        $s='We want to go home';
        echo preg_replace('@^(\w{2})@','($1)',$s );
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

```
<?php
$string = "We want home";
$parts = explode(' ', $string);
$parts[0] = '('.$parts[0].')';
$string = implode($parts, ' ');
var_dump($string); // outputs "(We) want home"
```

You could as well use `regex`.